# How to run only the CompileTypeScript target in a .csproj with MSBuild exe?

Tags: typescript, msbuild

**Context**

I have standard .csproj and an imported standard typescript compile target in it.
Nothing custom, all created by VS 2017, and the 2.7.2 version TypeScript tooling extension (and/or the nuget package?) for VS.

When I run MsBuild against the default target (no /t: switch) all works and among the others the CompileTypeSrcipt target run successfully and actually compiles the .ts files.

I would like to run, just the typescript build task from command line, using MSBuild. I know the syntax using the /t:CompileTypeSrcipt, everything seems OK, except: When I run the against the target CompileTypeScript, it reports 0 errors, but does nothing.

**Question:**

How can I successfully run MsBuild from the command line against my .csproj file, only build the the typescript task?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, have you reported this to the TS guys? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: No I did not. Because I has no build skills I thought I was missing something. Still not sure.